# I want to give a role to a user that has a changed nickname

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I want to give a role to a guy that has a changed nickname on the server. It works but if you don't have a changed nickname `${config.prefix}addrole <user> <role>`, but if he has a changed nickname I need to remove the space between the role and the user to work.

```
module.exports.run = async(bot, message, args) => {
  if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_ROLES")) return message.reply("no⚠");
  if (args[0] == "help") {
    message.reply(`${config.prefix}addrole <User> <role>`);
    return;
  }
  let rMember = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[0]));
  if (!rMember) return message.reply(`${config.prefix}addrole <user> <role>`);
  let rRole = args.join('  ').slice(22);
  if (!rRole) return message.reply("Put a role!");
  let gRole = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === rRole);
  if (!gRole) return message.reply("Didn't find that role");

  if (rMember.roles.has(gRole.id)) return message.reply("Already has that role");
  await (rMember.addRole(gRole.id));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you've put `message.mentions.users.first()` instead of `message.mentions.members.first()`. You want to add a role to a guild member, not to a  discord user. Try to put `let rMember = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[0]);`